# how to get <input of type=hidden> with FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the value of a hidden input in code behind with the following code. I am trying to cast it but it cannot find it , any help ?

```
((HtmlControl)FindControl("contentId"))
```

I declare it in aspx with the following code:

```
    <input id="contentId"  type="hidden" />
```

I dont want to runat server because i have my own reasons

Comment: How is your `input` declared in the markup?

Comment: If your control is server control and it is reside on some other control you need to recursively find. See http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/05/06/asp.net-recursive-findcontrol-amp-extension-methods.aspx

Comment: Without `runat="server"` your only option to dynamically access the hidden input is by using client side scripting. Your choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access a HTML control at server side (in your C# code), you need to first add the runat="server" attribute. So, your markup should look like

```
<input type="hidden" id="contentId" runat="server"/>
```

Now, in the code behind you can use the control by its id `contentId` itself if the code behind got generated properly.

Please let us know why you are forced to use the FindControl in the first place as it can be accessed by using the id directly.

***Update***

As per the comment below, the user for some reason is not interested in making this input a server side control. Then the only possibility by which you can read the values at server side is as below. But this is not advised as any changes to the name goes unnoticed and breaks at runtime.

```
<input type="hidden" id="contentId" name="contentName" runat="server"/>
```

In Code

`this.Request.Forms["contentName"]` would return the hidden value.

Comment: i dont want to use runat server property because i have my own resons.

Comment: will you please state your reasons for that ?

Comment: If you are not going to use runat=server you cannot access the control in the code behind. You can only see the value coming in Request.Froms["<nameofControl>"]

Comment: sorry , i ask the @user1292656 whats the reaosn behind not using runat server

Comment: @rahularyansharma I was also providing clarification only to user1292656

Answer (score 2):

Try to search it on the page this way

```
HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)page.FindControl("contentId");
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the value:

```
HiddenField h = (HiddenField)Gridview.FindControl("HiddenFieldName");
```

Then with that you can put it into a string, if you wish to.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

`string s=((HiddenField)Panel1.FindControl("contentId")).Value;`

Here panel is the container control. This may be a grid or anything else or even a master page. But if you are using FindControl, i think the control may be inside some container.

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlInputHidden hf = Page.FindControl("contentId") as HtmlInputHidden;
string hfValue = hf.Value;
```